# Chartjs - uncaught reference error chart is not defined Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

In my laravel project i'm using adminlte dashboard. Also i'm using chartjs in adminlte dashboard. **Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined** error occurred. I tried many solutions but still error is same. What is the problem that happen and how to solve this?

I added code example in chartjs documentation: but this is not working;

```js
                <canvas id="timechart" width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
                <script>
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('timechart').getContext('2d');
                        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            // The type of chart we want to create
                            type: 'line',
                            // The data for our dataset
                            data: {
                                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: 'My First dataset',
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                                }]
                            },
                            // Configuration options go here
                            options: {}
                        });
                </script>
```

add chartjs in main layout:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/Chart.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Where are you importing ChartJS?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/Chart.js') }}"></script>` I added like this, in main layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the import js on the top above the function that you call from the js. So easiest way is put `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/Chart.js') }}"></script>` in the header. Or put in footer but above `new Chart(ctx,{})`. Below is example working snippet code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="timechart" width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
                <script>
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('timechart').getContext('2d');
                        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            // The type of chart we want to create
                            type: 'line',
                            // The data for our dataset
                            data: {
                                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                                datasets: [{
                                    label: 'My First dataset',
                                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                                }]
                            },
                            // Configuration options go here
                            options: {}
                        });
                </script>
```